# How to NOT display text in a text field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a site **[here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/)**.

**Here's the code from my little form...**

```
<form method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search" target="_blank"> 
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0"> 
        <tr>
            <td> 
                <input type="text" name="q" size="25" maxlength="50" value="" id="google" /> 
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </td>
        </tr> 


        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="font-size:75%">
                <input type="radio" name="search" value="google.com" onclick="act('public library ')"/> Libraries
                <input type="radio" name="search" value="google.com" onclick="act('subway OR FedEx ')"/> Fax
                <!--<input type="radio" name="search" value="google.com" onclick="act('ice cream ')"/> Ice Cream-->                    
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</form>
```

**Here's the Javascript related to the above HTML (maybe it has something to do with my question)...**

```
function act(change) {
    myOption = change;
    document.getElementById("google").value = myOption;
    }
```

There's a JSFiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/5EEXD/2/)**. (Thanks to @koala_dev)

**On my site**, if you click '**Libraries**', then "**public library**" will display in the text box. I left a space to enter the zip code, and then the results are displayed in a Google page in another window when Search is clicked.

**What I would like to see happen...**

I want the user to click '**Libraries**', but I don't want the text "**public library**" to display. I just want the user to enter their zip code and hit search. I want the "**public library**" text to stay hidden.

**Edit:** Sorry... The search field is the one on the top right-hand side of the page. There's a label there that says **Find it here! (Enter Zip Code)**...

Comment: Can you just change "<input type='text'" to "<input type='hidden'"?

Comment: That is not possible unless you set up a google custom search. for now you need to do document.getElementById("google").value += " " +myOption;

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle that works http://jsfiddle.net/5EEXD/1/, you need to use the option "No wrap - in `<head>`" so the function is declared beforehand

Comment: @David - that removes the entire text box.

Comment: Also PLEASE use appropriate `<label>` tags for radio inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my version

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/SQLGr/)

```
$(function() {
  $("form").on("submit",function(e) {
    var zip = $("#google").val();
    var what = $("input[name='what']:checked").val();
    what=what?zip+" "+what:zip;  
    if (what) $("#google").val(what);
    else e.preventDefault();  
  });
});
```

You may want to reset the field by removing the radio value from it when focussing the field

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd want to tie a function to the submit button and in there prefix the input ed value with "public library " or "subway OR FedEx"

Comment: How would I do that? JS isn't really my forte...yet.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use ajax to send your requests to google, then you could control exactly how things are handled in every event. It also would remove the need for a page refresh or pop-up window that could be blocked by pop-up blockers?

```
$("input[name=search]").change(function () {
     //alert($(this).val());
     option = $(this).val();
     var $url = "https://www.google.com/search/" + option;
     $.ajax({
         url: $url,
         type: 'GET',
         beforeSend: function () {
             //do something before submitting
         },
         success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
             //success do something with the data you get back
             console.log(data);
             $("#results").html(data);
         },
         error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             //something broke
             $("#results").html(errorThrown);
         }
     });
 });


    <form>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="q" size="25" maxlength="50" value="" id="google" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="font-size:75%">
                    <input type="radio" id='radiobtn1' name="search" value="Libraries" />Libraries
                    <input type="radio" id='radiobtn2' name="search" value="Fax" />Fax
                    <!--<input type="radio" name="search" value="google.com" onclick="act('ice cream ')"/>Ice Cream--></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the the radio button `search`, it fires the javascript code `act('public library ')`.  Looking through your code, you have a function act, below:

```
 function act(change) {
 myOption = change;
 document.getElementById("google").value = myOption;
}
```

Your issue lies with the last part of that code `document.getElementByID("google").value = myOption`.  It doesn't seem like that javascript does anything else.  Did you mean for it to do anything else afterwards?  If not, you don't have to fire that javascript in the first place.

Comment: But when I remove it, it dis-allows the ability to search with the pre-defined 'public library' or 'subway OR FedEx'... it only searches the zip code.